# Missing AsyncResult in Windows store apps?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-store-apps

I am porting a .Net library that makes heavy use of the [Asynchronous Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx)(APM) to a Windows store app library.

I would like to keep the Method definitions the same so other code making use of the library will just work with the Windows store app version. (i.e. as much as I prefer it, no async await pattern).

Problem is though Windows store apps seem compatible with the APM the concrete [AsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.asyncresult.aspx) class is missing. As a result one cannot get the delegate instance that `BeginInvoke()` was called on in the callback and call `EndInvoke()`:

```
public MyObject EndDoSomething (IAsyncResult result)
{
    // Retrieve the delegate.
    AsyncResult asyncResult = (AsyncResult)result; // Not possible in Windows store app - no AsyncResult

    // Wait for the WaitHandle to become signaled.
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    // Call EndInvoke to retrieve the results.
    MyObject rv = ((MyAsynchronousDelegate)asyncResult.AsyncDelegate).EndInvoke(result);

    // Close the wait handel
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close()  // Close() is also missing

    return rv;
}
```

So what is one to do?

Comment: If you're going to create a library *for Windows Store apps* why would you want to impose the horror of the APM model on them, rather than exposing a TAP-based solution? Bear in mind that the *rest* of an application using your library would have to be modified to use the newer-style asynchrony anyway, so I don't think you're really saving anyone much trouble - and you're making it much more painful for *new* applications who want to use your library.

Comment: Good point, because there is such a large number of apps using the library already compared to new apps that will target Windows store apps, even new apps tend to target the traditional .Net framework. Perhaps I might force their hand anyway...

Comment: You're specifically porting it for Windows Store apps though. Any new apps which *aren't* targeting Windows Store presumably would use the original library anyway. So think about what a Windows Store app developer would want to use.

Comment: @user1896654: There is a [NuGet library](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) that brings `async` support to .NET 4.0 and other platforms. It's in beta, but it is an option.